# How to count data array based unique key in php laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i have data as array like this:

```
$array =[
         [
          "Media Masa (Koran \/ Majalah, dsb)",
          "Internet",
          "Teman \/ Keluarga",
          "Coworking Space"
         ],
         [
          "Iklan TV",
          "Media Masa (Koran \/ Majalah, dsb)",
          "Teman \/ Keluarga",
          "Coworking Space",
          "Mili Network",
          "Lainnya"
         ],
         [
          "Block71",
          null,
          null,
          "Mili Network",
          "UKM Indonesia",
          "TOP Karir"
         ],
         false
        ];
```

how to merge this data in one array and count based value name, like:

- Media Masa (Koran / Majalah, dsb) = 2
- Internet =1
- Teman / Keluarga= 2
- Coworking Space=2
- Iklan TV=1
- Mili Network=2
- Lainnya=1
- Block71=1
- UKM Indonesia=1
- TOP Karir=1

Null and false value no include!

Comment: have you made any attempt? if so can you provide that

Comment: I would break this problem into 2 parts: a) unpack the array of arrays into one array.. a.ka. flatten the array. some libraries have a .flat method for arrays b) loop through the flattened array and count distinct elements e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-distinct-elements-in-an-array/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten the array and filter out any value that is not a string using [`array_walk_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive) then just use [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values) function:

```
$array = [
  [
   "Media Masa (Koran \/ Majalah, dsb)",
   "Internet",
   "Teman \/ Keluarga",
   "Coworking Space"
  ],
  [
   "Iklan TV",
   "Media Masa (Koran \/ Majalah, dsb)",
   "Teman \/ Keluarga",
   "Coworking Space",
   "Mili Network",
   "Lainnya"
 ],
 [
   "Block71",
   null,
   null,
   "Mili Network",
   "UKM Indonesia",
   "TOP Karir"
 ],
   false
];
array_walk_recursive($array, function($v) use (&$r){ if (gettype($v) == 'string') {$r[]=$v;}});
```

If you `print_r($r)`, the output will be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Media Masa (Koran \/ Majalah, dsb)
    [1] => Internet
    [2] => Teman \/ Keluarga
    [3] => Coworking Space
    [4] => Iklan TV
    [5] => Media Masa (Koran \/ Majalah, dsb)
    [6] => Teman \/ Keluarga
    [7] => Coworking Space
    [8] => Mili Network
    [9] => Lainnya
    [10] => Block71
    [11] => Mili Network
    [12] => UKM Indonesia
    [13] => TOP Karir
)
```

Then just count the value:

```
print_r(array_count_values($r));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Media Masa (Koran \/ Majalah, dsb)] => 2
    [Internet] => 1
    [Teman \/ Keluarga] => 2
    [Coworking Space] => 2
    [Iklan TV] => 1
    [Mili Network] => 2
    [Lainnya] => 1
    [Block71] => 1
    [UKM Indonesia] => 1
    [TOP Karir] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you to tried use countBy()? is part of collection laravel https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-countBy